# Java Spring Web Socket With STOMP & Sock JS Facing Issue With Proxy

Tags: proxy, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs, angular14

I have implemented websockets in Spring with STOMP & Sock js & it is working as expected. The issue arises when we  are moving our application to offshore environment where every request first connects to the front-end & the front-end then redirects this request to backend which results in 500 internal server error.  If the front-end tries to connect to backend directly (skipping the redirection part), it works perfectly. Is there any way to handle this in java spring security config or websocket config ? (The front-end team is using Angular 14)

Below is my code snippet in WebsocketConfig.java

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
    messageBrokerRegistry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app"); 
    messageBrokerRegistry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I tried using following in Spring security by overriding 'configure' method :

```
.headers().addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(new StaticAllowFromStrategy(URI.create("https://FrontEndServerAddress/")))) ;
```